# Error No component factory found for ... in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a `ModalComponent`

if I declare it like so in my `app.module.ts` It works fine and I can use it in my app.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ModalComponent],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent],
  ...
})
```

Now If I do the same in a my page `page.module.ts` and try to use the modal there it doesn't work. Why?

I get this error `No component factory found for ... yadaayaydayada`

I've read this could be outdated scripts issue because of ionic 4, so I made sure my `package.json` base is identical to their templates.

My ideal solution would be to display the modal from a component within a page, but I can't get it to work due to the above error.

How do I need to register my component so I can bind it programmatically within a page and/or inside a component nested in that page?

**More Information Below**

This is how I display my modal:

```
async presentModal() {
  const modal = await this.ui.modalController.create({
    component: ModalComponent,
  });

  return await modal.present();
}
```

- My nested component & modal component don't have @NgModule's

Complete `app.module.ts`

```
//Omitting Imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ModalComponent],
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule, // <-- This is where the Page is imported
  ],
  providers: [
    OAuthService,
    UrlHelperService,
    InAppBrowser,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Camera,
    WebView,
    File,
    FileTransfer,
    VideoEditor,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: UnAuthorizedService, multi: true, }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './battles/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }, <-- page registered here
   //omitting other routes
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Here is my `tabs.router.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'battles',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../user/user.module#UserPageModule' <-- Here is my page (I think this might be lazy loaded not sure.)
          }
        ]
      }
      //Omitting other routes
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the `page.module`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { UserPage } from './user.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [UserPage],
  // I would declare my modal like this same as in the app.module, 
  // but this isn't working, for now I'm storing it in app.module
  //    declarations: [UserPage, ModalComponent],
  //    entryComponents: [ModalComponent],

})
export class UserPageModule { }
```

Full Error:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

I think because my page is lazy loaded I am facing [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324) which my lack of Angular knowledge stops me from understanding how to solve it.

Comment: Have you imported page module in  `app.module`? If yes then please include the code for the rest of `app.module` metadata and also `page.module`

Comment: @jal_a I have updated the question with the relative logical path to the page from the app.module in my app.

Comment: So where are you declaring modal component that it doesn't work? I don't see it in any nested module. Aside from that include the error properly please.

Comment: @jal_a I updated the question, I would declare my Modal in my Page but that's where I get the error.

Comment: So new question. What is `this.ui.modalController`? Do you have a service that creates the modal? You should try creating and opening the modal in the component itself. It's difficult to help because one can't get enough info from the code snippets. Best would be if you can reproduce this in a minimal ionic app to rule out any specific module structure in your project.

Answer (score 2):

This Answere is from "razmans" in the [Ionic FrameWork Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-4-need-to-know-how-to-work-the-modal-controller/136414/4)

Import into app.module.ts first the PageModule and then only you can import into Home.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FirstPageModule} from './first/first.module'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,FirstPageModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,AlertController,ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {FirstPage} from '../first/first.page';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor( private modalCtrl:ModalController,private alertCtrl:AlertController) {}

  async moveToFirst()
  {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
     component: FirstPage
   });

   return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

This will open my modal. Closing it is a whole other thing, instead of getting ViewController to do it, you need to get ModalController to do it with this.modalCtrl.dismiss. Here’s how I closed the modal from first.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'first',
  templateUrl: './first.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.page.scss'],
})
export class FirstPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private nav:NavController,private modalCtrl:ModalController) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  closeModal()
  {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just import modal page module into imports array of your app.module.ts

app.module.ts

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ModalPageModule } from './modal/modal.module';

    imports: [ ..., ModalPageModule]
```

Then in your page that requires the modal, import the modal page itself and ModalController

modal.page

```js
    import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { ModalPage } from '../modal/modal.page';

    @Component({
    selector: ...,
    templateUrl: ...,
    styleUrls: ...,
    })

    export class MyPageThatRequiresModal implements OnInit {

    constructor(public modalController: ModalController) { }

    ...

     async presentModal() {
      const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalPage,
        componentProps: { value: 123 }
     });

     return await modal.present();

    }

    ...


    }
```